# How would one go about solving this conjecture concerning exponential Diophantine equations?

Tags: diophantine-equations, conjectures, collatz-conjecture

I’ve been working on the Collatz Conjecture, and I believe I’ve reduced it to a more tractable problem. Unless there are some errors I’ve overlooked, I have managed to reduce the Collatz Conjecture to an exponential Diophantine equation(EDE). In an attempt to solve it, I’ve looked at linear forms in logarithms( but have been unsuccessful) and the proof of Catalans conjecture ( which again I could glean no pathway to solving this EDE).

$\forall k \in \mathbb{N} \exists a, b, c, m,  n \in \mathbb{N} \cup \{0\} :$
$$\frac{3^{a} - 2^{b}}{2^{c}} = 1 - \frac{3^{m}}{2^{n}}k$$

Any tips, pathways to solutions, or outright solutions would be greatly appreciated! If you want to see how I reduced it to this EDE, then I’ll be happy to show you.

Comment: I fixed one formatting issue here, but all the subscripts make this hard to read, just as with your previous question.

Comment: I am interested how you reduced to this EDE.

Comment: I’ll add the link to vixra and my Quora space. 
Vixra: https://vixra.org/abs/2304.0050.   My Quora space :  https://mathscape.quora.com/Good-evening-everyone-I-tried-finding-ways-to-attach-the-pdf-file-but-Quora-doesn-t-allow-that-I-wanted-to-submit-th?ch=17&oid=106532992&share=53cbc3c1&srid=uV3oPz&target_type=post

Comment: I’ve also tried looking at S-unit equations. Still doing some research though.

Comment: How do the values of $a,b,c,m,n,k$ relate to "solutions" to the Collatz conjecture? Are we to assume you are proposing every solution to your equation represents a loop containing $m+n$ steps, of which $m$ are odd and $n$ even? If so, the number of solutions to your equation for which $k\in\Bbb Z_2^\times$ (i.e. a 2-adic unit) are enumerated by the base $2$ Lyndon words of length $n+m$. This is because the functions orbits are topologically conjugate to the tent map.

Comment: Please take a look at my paper linked above @it'sahirecarbaby

Comment: @JohnEaton that won't work for me. How are e.g. the solutions $(-1)$ and $(1,2)$ represented in your equation?  How is the solution $(-5,-7,-10)$ represented?

Comment: For example, put $k =1$ , then we can set $a = b =1$ , $c = 2$ , $m =1$ , and $n = 2$. This corresponds to the shortened Collatz map that takes $1$ to $2$ and $2$ to $1$.

Comment: Thanks @JohnEaton for giving me $(1,2)$ which narrows it down a bit but are you able to indicate how the solutions $(-1)$ and $(-5,-7,-10)$ are represented in your $a,b,c,m,n$?

Comment: It’s the same process, $(-1) -> (-1)$. I.e $\frac{( 3(-1) + 1)}{2} = \frac{3}{2}(-1) + \frac{3 - 2}{2} = -1$ . Thus, $  m = n = a = b = c = 1 $. I’m sure you can figure out the other fixed points.

Comment: I have come across a huge misstep in my paper. Therefore, I would like to close this question. I will not delete it, but I no longer am seeking answers for the above question.